# Unordered list pushing the parent element down

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one nested in the other, i.e. the `#messages` div is inside the `#mainContent` div. The `#messages` div should be 0px from the top of its parent. Everything is fine until i put a `unordered list` inside it, then it pushes the whole div down from the whole `#messages` div down by a few pixels.

If i put `margin-top:0px;` on the `ul` element, everything is fine again, but i want the ul to be `margin-top:10px;` from it's `#messages` parent. If i put `margin-top:10px;` it again pushes `#messages` 10px from `#mainContent`.

Can someone please explain why this is happening, and can someone provide a clean solution for this?

Thank you, it's `jsfiddle` is:

http://jsfiddle.net/wtKuP/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Can someone please explain why this is happening, and can someone provide a clean solution for this?*"

The top margins of a block-level element and its first in-flow block-level child will always [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). There are many ways to avoid this (read the above link for a complete list) - one is to just add `overflow: hidden` to the parent of the `<ul>` as this creates a new [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) and prevents the standard margin collapsing behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtKuP/22/

From the 2.1 Spec, Section 8.3.1:

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.

Comment: I will have to checkout what the purpose and options with `overflow` really are since i have never used it before, thank you `Adrift` for the nice answer!

Comment: This has to be the most well written answer I saw today... +1

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

on both `divs`. Then `ul` will have a 10px margin from messages div, but messages div will have no margin with `maincontent`.

Answer (score 0):

Add ul:{margin:0;}.  Better use eric myers reset.css which will remove browser inconsistence

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[JSFiddle updated with what you were asking for](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/wtKuP/27/)

```
<div id="mainContent">
<div id="messages">
<ul>
<li>Remove the UL and LI, and the #messages div will be 0px from the top of the parent div #mainContent. Why?</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And then...

```
div#mainContent {
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    left:50%;
}
#mainContent > #messages {
    margin: 0;
    width:499px;
    height:525px;
    background-color:red;
}

#messages ul { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```